# After macOS update, client can't connect to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, macos, firefox, server, phpmyadmin

I've had phpMyAdmin running on a Mac mini with OS X Server (10.11.6) for years with no problems. But since updating my MacBook Pro client to Catalina (and now Big Sur), it will no longer connect to the database--it simply acts like the server doesn't exist, whether I use the server's LAN address or the public one. I can connect to phpMyAdmin with other Macs running older versions of macOS with no problems, and the MacBook will connect to the mini as a normal file and web server--the problem seems to be just with phpMyAdmin.

Suspect this must have something to do with tighter security in newer macOS versions, but I don't know where to look.

Update: just discovered that, on my client MacBook, `Safari` can in fact access the phpMyAdmin server, but `Firefox` can't (Firefox is my default browser).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327503/under-catalina-macos-10-15-php-under-apache-has-restricted-access-to-some-files

Comment: Thanks, Bill, but that issue seems to be about access rights on the *server*. My server runs El Capitan. Don't see why a new client macOS would affect this (but I'm prepared to be convinced).

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Given your update, this appears to be isolated to some behavior of Firefox, since the other browser works. So we know it's not a network problem or an OS firewall or something like that. This question is seeming less and less like a code question. [Stack Overflow wants to limit questions on this site to questions about specific coding problems.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Perhaps https://superuser.com or https://apple.stackexchange.com would be better sites on which to ask.

Comment: I suggest trying with a new Firefox profile to make sure there's nothing strange about your existing profile. There could be some strange network setting, antivirus add-on, or odd cache problem causing issues that would be narrowed down by testing with a new (and clean) profile.